# Closed morphism of products of k-schemes with a field extension of k implies closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry, extension-field, schemes

This is from exercise 9.2.J of Ravi Vakil's notes on algebraic geometry [here](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/)

We have a morphism of $k$ schemes $\pi:X \rightarrow Y$. $l/k$ is a field extension. We want to show if $\pi\times_k l: X\times_k l\rightarrow Y\times_k l$ is a closed embedding then $\pi$ also is one.

If you assume $\pi$ is affine this is fairly simple. I am having a lot of trouble proving it without that hypothesis. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you done the exercise establishing that "closed immersions are affine-local on the target"? If so, what difficulties do you encounter applying that to this exercise?

Comment: So I can reduce it to the case where $Y$ can be affine but $X$ is still arbitrary. Now I am able to show $\pi\times_k l$ will induce an isomorphism between $\text{Spec}(Y/J\otimes_{k}l)$ and $X\times_k l$ where $J$ is some ideal of $Y$. I am unable to show X must be $\text{Spec}(Y/J)$.

Comment: In the earlier comment I had misunderstood some of the subtlety involved here, and for that I apologize. One potential answer is that the property of $\pi$ being affine is stable under descent, so in fact $\pi_l$ affine (as it's a closed immersion) implies $\pi$ affine. A source for this is Stacksproject 02L5 or EGA IV2 2.7.1.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be exactly what I need.